# angular more function in function in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function

I got task to make some http request with angular. I am very new with angular, and I hot specific rules how I should done that app. Can you tell me is it possible to do this what I will describe or not, and if is possible how?

In view I need to have a couple of buttons or regular links which will call functions in controller. So I need one controller with more than one function, and I need data from each function to be available only when call is made. I made on function in controller:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('userManager')
    .controller('userDataController', userDataController);


function userDataController(auth, $scope,$http){

    var vm = this;
    vm.loggedUser = auth;
    vm.allUsers=[];

    function allUsersGet() {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/allUsers',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            vm.allUsers = response.data;
        });
    }

}
})();
```

But I cannot get this data in view. Can anyone tell me how to write link in view and data printing, and do I need change function in controller for a little bit?

Thanks in advance

Comment: need to bind function(s) to be called from view to your $scope

Comment: can I avoid $scope? And if I can't how to bind?

Comment: can u show your view code or tell how u r calling/populating

Comment: why would you want to avoid scope? $scope.allUsersGet = function()...

Comment: I don't calling because I don't know how

Comment: I am not sure why I want to avoid, I am new in angular and I figure out if is something in scope that is available every time, but I want to be available when you click to call that function, and when you call another to be available only data from that function. Am I wrong?

Comment: It IS good practice to avoid $scope and use the newer component-like approach, where you bind data to your controllers or share it with services.

Comment: No worries Sasa ,you can call this function using simple onclick attribute of a button,or if u want to call using angular?Refer my answer below to see how to bind using 'this' on ur view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a controller in any template like this:

```
<div ng-controller="userDataController as $ctrl">
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.allUsersGet()">get users data</button>
    <pre>
    {{ $ctrl.allUsers }}
    </pre>
</div>
```

You migtht also want to bind the allUsersGet function to the controller. Instead of

```
function allUsersGet() { ...
```

write

```
this.allUsersGet = function() { ...
```

Comment: $ctrl is nothing special, by the way. It's just a convention taken from angular components. You could use any other name instead.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me very fast. I did get some response now just to take data which I want to. This question can be closed.

Comment: Hi @Sasa. I'm glad I could help. If you feel like you found your answer, please accept it. With more reputation you'll also be able to upvote questions. Closing a question is only done if the question is problematic/bad - which is not the case here, I think.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-controller="userDataController as userData" >
 <div ng-repeat="user in userData.allUsers">
   {{user}}
 </div>
</div>
```

For binding data using 'this',u can use the above approach.

Answer (score 0):

Change on retrieval of your data to set the data to the `$scope`

```
}).then(function (response) {
    vm.allUsers = response.data;
    $scope.allUsers = response.data;
});
```

On your view you can loop the data as following:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in allUsers">
  {{user}}
</div>
```